# Could not find apk

Tags: android

I installed Eclipse/ ADT in Ubuntu on my computer. I am able to run Chapter 4 To do list examples Part 1-3 successfully (of Reto Meier's PA4AD book), but when I run Chapter_4_Compass, I get the following error. Please help immediately:

```
[2013-05-20 18:34:55 - Chapter_4_Compass] ------------------------------
[2013-05-20 18:34:55 - Chapter_4_Compass] Android Launch!
[2013-05-20 18:34:55 - Chapter_4_Compass] adb is running normally.
[2013-05-20 18:34:55 - Chapter_4_Compass] Could not find Chapter_4_Compass.apk!
```

Thanks,

Shekar M.

Comment: Post your manifest file

Comment: When I see this, I just click run again, and it works..

Answer (score 14):

Right Click on your app -> properties -> android. Uncheck 'Is Library'.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Android SDK Tools v22, make sure that you have the most up-to-date versions of Android SDK Platform-tools and Android SDK Build-tools also installed (rev. 17).
1) Open the Android SDK Manager
2) Update all of the items in the tools folder
*This may require you to restart the SDK manager a few times.

Answer (score 3):

Here is somthong that just worked for me. I had the same problem as the original poster after moving a project from my PC to a laptop and back again to do some programming whilst on the go.

I tried everything suggested by CRUSADER much of which has worked for many others on SO (if you read the other threads on this subject).

What I noticed was that in the project's Bin directory the APK file was not there. Instead there was a Jar file containing the project name. I know as some point during the build and run process a jar gets initial made and then converted to an APK (Dexing I believe part of this process is called).

Anyway to cut a long story short. I got an APK from one of my earlier project backups. Pasted it into the bin folder folder and now I'm able to build and run my project again.

Weird but it works, like so much of Android/Eclipse.

Comment: Tried a million other suggestions on SO, this was the one that worked for me! Nice work Andrew

Answer (score 2):

Try following steps:-

- Restart Eclipse (Solves issue most of time...)
- Right-click your project and select Android tools --> Fix project
  properties.
- Right-click your project and select Build path --> Configure build
  path.. In here, check if all libraries are imported correctly..
- If above doesn't works then go to Help --> Install new software and
  then Help --> Install new software . Follow this steps till your
  eclipse says no update found or its upto date..
- Restart Eclise once again..

Hope this helps..

Comment: Doesn't help me. I have the same issue and am at a loss, doing hours of overtime to try and get this issue fixed. Happened when I spend the day developing the project on my laptop.  I then moved it back to my man PC and got this issue. Tried everything on your list and some several times. One clue I can note is that in my bun directory there is Jar file rather than an APK file with the project name.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a little old post, but someone can have similar problem. I had an ' Could not find android-support-v7-appcompat.apk!' error.
I had to remove appcompat from Java Build Path and add a .jar with the same name.

Right click your project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Projects
There I had android-support-v7-appcompat project. Remove it.
Now click Libraries tab.
Your android-support-v7-appcompat.jar should be missing. Click add 'JARs...' and:

1. If you have android-support-v7-appcompat project in your workspace, expand it go to bin folder and there you have it :D Select it and hit OK. It should work now.
2. If you DON'T have android-support-v7-appcompat project, click 'Add External JARs...' and go to "drive:\your android sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\libs\".
   There you should have your jar.